# iOS7: How to implement Section Index like Contacts on iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In iOS7, the Section Index of Contact app shows fewer indexes.

For example, "A ● C ● E ... **M ● P** ● R..."

[image: iOS7 contacts]

> 

I know these two delegate methods:

> -(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
>
> -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex

But I don't know how to implement such an shorter index. Can anyone gives me a hint?

Thanks very much!

--edit--

Take a look at the index: "M ● P ● R...", if I swipe from 'M' to 'P', tableView shows section 'M' then 'N' then 'O' and then 'P', which means it uses three indexes index to 4 sections.

--edit--

All right, this kind of index is automatically generated.

If the frame of table is not large enough to show the index, then the index is shown as a doted index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an automatic behavior of the standard index. The index in Contacts is a normal index with all the chars, but you are using an iPhone 4 or 4s and  when there are not enough space some letters are replaced with dots. If you open the app with a iPhone 5 or 5s you will see all the letters.

Comment: Yes, I've observed this behaviour. But I want to shorten my index for 3.5inch screens, just like Contact does.

Comment: This kind of index is automatically generated. I think too much on this. If dot not appears in the index, then the index is not long enough to show dot. After I shorten the tableView, the index with dot is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for ? Hum I've replace dot per heart ;-D

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"A",@"♥",@"C",@"♥",@"E"]];
    [ma insertObject:UITableViewIndexSearch atIndex:0]; //add magnifier at top
    return ma; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, Since this method only returns an index with length == 5. When I swipe from A to E, then tableView only shows the first 5 sections. While, in Contact, for such index: "M ● P ● R...", if I swipe from 'M' to 'P', tableView shows section 'M' then 'N' then 'O' and then 'P', which means it uses three indexes index to 4 sections.

Comment: this should be managed via `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex`

Comment: But I have no idea how to match fewer indexes to more sections. I read the decimation for this method and the parameter index is the index selected in sectionIndex and returned integer is the index of section in tableView. How to match it?

Comment: if you have sections A,B,C,D,E...Y,Z (26 sections), if you return in sectionIndexTitlesForTableView, an array with A,.,D,.,G,.,J... when you will swipe from D to G, you will get atIndex = 3 (for D), 4 (for dot), 5 (for G). you have to return 4 (when atIndex = 3), 5 or 6 (when atIndex = 4), 7 (when atIndex = 5), or (int)((atIndex-1)*1.5)+1). Of course you will never stop on B,E,H,K...